# BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard to expose schemas as WCF service issue when browse services through IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

> Server Error in '/OrderProcessingService' Application.
>
> This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
>   Parameter name: item
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
>   Parameter name: item
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Can someone help to resolve this issue with expose schema using BizTalk WCF publishing wizard?

> After changing web.config file as below

```
   </system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
```

Getting different error and trace as below:

> Stack Trace: 
>   [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=9.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>      Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BtsServiceHostBase.ConfigureClientCredentials() +0
>      Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BtsServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +1173
>      Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WebServiceHost`3.InitializeRuntime() +130
>      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +63
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +563
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +135
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +654
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/OrderProcessingService/OrderProcessingService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=9.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
>      System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +15778592
>     System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +15698937
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +265
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +227
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Comment: It's Done - Thx !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first error basically means that you have tried publishing multiple different protocols in the same App Pool.   You need to have separate IIS App pools for the different protocols.

Also make sure that the Application Pool is running with the Isolated Host user.

Comment: I checked '/OrderProcessingService'  services running under separate App Pool  has access to isolated host now I have different error though Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=9.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: It's working fine one's I changed App Pool .NET framework version from v2.0  to v4.0 !!! Thanks.

Comment: Also make sure to set "multipleSiteBindingsEnabled" to "TRUE" in your web.config file as I said early !!!